# PostgreSQL 12 installion problem with Ubuntu 18.04 docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to install Postgresql-12 on an Ubuntu container, but it is giving the following error.

> Reading state information...
> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12
> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-12

It looks like the Ubuntu 18 container doesn't support PostgreSQL version 12.
Is there any way I can install postgresl version 12 on Ubuntu 18.04 container?
Any help is appreaciated. The docker file code snippet is given below.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg dirmngr

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y software-properties-common postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are using the wrong APT package repository. Replace

```
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

with

```
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

and try again. `precise` is the codename for Ubuntu 12.04 (which has reached its end of life years ago), but your Dockerfile uses the newer Ubuntu 18.04. The codename for Ubuntu 18.04 is `bionic`.

**Edit:**
Since I'm having problems connecting to the key server given in the Dockerfile I took a look at the [PostgreSQL website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and aquired the key via `wget` as shown there. The Dockerfile does now look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg dirmngr wget
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y software-properties-common postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12
```

Notable changes are the installation of `wget` (2nd line) and using it to get the key (4th line).